# Function coding error concatenating quotes I think

Tags: functions

Function:

```
function get_highest_bid(){
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = get_post_id();
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "jwp_bids";
    $highest_bid = $wpdb->get_var(
        "Select max(bid_amt)
        FROM " . $table . "
        WHERE post_id = " . $postid . ';" );'
    echo $highest_bid;
}
```

Error:
Unexpected echo line blah blah.

Question:
What did I do wrong concatenating that `; );` at the end? Concatenating when quotes are part of the statement confuses the dickens out of me. Any tips on that?

Thanks!

Comment: the last ; should be outside the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're evaluating php variables in a string(interpolating the variables directly in a string), it's best to use double quotes, this way you don't have to concatenante with dots.

```
function get_highest_bid( ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = get_post_id();
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "jwp_bids";
    $highest_bid = $wpdb->get_var(
        "Select max(bid_amt)
         FROM $table
         WHERE post_id ='$postid';"
         );
    echo $highest_bid;
}
```

Comment: You should also mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Why don't we single quote $table??

Comment: For mysql, backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected one:

`$highest_bid = $wpdb->get_var(
    "Select max(bid_amt)
    FROM " . $table . "
    WHERE post_id = " . $postid . ";" );`

Just replace yours with above.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm sure it will work and will use it momentarily. So, it appears as though I should be thinking of isolating the variable only. Correct?

Comment: Yes and what you were doing wrong is...you were including the closing bracket and semicolon as well in the string concatenation. That was creating problem :)

Comment: Thanks so much! That really clarifies concatenation for me. Previously I was trying to isolate each section before and after the periods. Thus the odd configuration at the end. Both answers are good ones!